Identify an animated fantasy adventure film
There is a movie, probably made in the US in the 90s or early 2000's, that involves a young woman who ends up in this bizarre, animated world. I remember that there are these flying book monsters with sharp teeth that keep chasing after her, repeating one word about how they want to eat something.
It's fairly surreal.
She is on a quest to find something. I think the girl may be live action, inside an animated world. The animation style is very unusual, somewhat similar to the like this picture attached below (the pic is from Madoka Magica, but that's not the movie I'm talking about)


Hi korkow. Welcome to movies&tv.SE :) Is this a feature length movie or a short film?

I think it might be Mirrormask (2005). It's a 2005 American fantasy film designed and directed by Dave McKean and written by Neil Gaiman from a story they developed together, starring Stephanie Leonidas, Jason Barry, Rob Brydon, and Gina McKee.
IMDB

Plot Wikipedia 

Helena (Stephanie Leonidas) works with her parents (Gina McKee and Rob
  Brydon) at their family circus, but desires to run away
  and join real life. At the next performance, after Helena and her
  mother have a heated argument, Helena's mother collapses and is taken
  to the hospital. Ten days later, while Helena is staying with her
  grandmother, she finds that the doctors determine that Helena's mother
  requires an operation, and Helena can only blame herself for the
  situation. That night, she wakes up in a dream-like state and leaves
  her building to find three performers outside. As they try to perform
  for Helena, a shadow encroaches on the area and two of the performers
  are consumed by it. The third performer, Valentine (Jason Barry), a
  juggler, helps to quickly direct Helena to safety through the use of
  magical flying books. She learns they are in the City of Light which
  is slowly being consumed by shadows, causing its widely varied
  citizens to flee. Soon Helena is mistaken for the Princess. She and
  Valentine are taken to the Prime Minister (Brydon). He explains that
  the Princess from the Land of Shadow stole a charm from the City of
  Light, leaving their White Queen (McKee) in a state of unnatural sleep
  and the City vulnerable to the Shadows. Helena notes the resemblance
  of the Queen and Minister to her mother and father, and offers to help
  recover the charm along with Valentine. They are unaware their actions
  are being watched by the Queen of Shadows (also McKee) who has
  mistaken Helena as the Princess of the Land of Shadows.
Helena and Valentine attempt to stay ahead of the shadows as they
  follow clues to the charm, learning that it is called "MirrorMask".
  Helena discovers that by looking through the windows of the buildings,
  she can see into her bedroom in the real world, through the drawings
  of windows that she created and hung on the wall of her room. She
  discovers that a doppelganger of herself is living there and behaving
  radically different from her. The doppelganger soon becomes aware of
  her presence in the drawings and begins to destroy them, causing parts
  of the fantasy world to collapse. Valentine betrays Helena to the
  Queen of Shadows in exchange for a large reward of jewels. The Queen's
  servants warp Helena's mind so she will believe she is the Princess of
  Shadows. Valentine has a change of heart and returns to the Queen's
  palace, and helps Helena to break the spell on her. They search the
  Princess' room, and Helena discovers the MirrorMask hidden in the
  Princess' mirror. They flee the castle with the charm.
As they escape to Valentine's flying tower, Helena realizes that her
  doppelganger in the real world is the Princess of Shadows, who had
  used the MirrorMask to step through the windows in Helena's drawings.
  The Princess destroys the rest of the drawings in Helena's room,
  preventing Helena from returning, and Helena and Valentine disappear
  in the collapsed world. The Princess takes the drawings to the
  building's roof to disperse the shreds into the wind, but discovers
  one more drawing Helena had made on the back of the roof door. Helena
  successfully returns to the real world, sending the Princess back to
  her realm. At the same time, the White Queen finally awakens and the
  two Cities are restored to their natural balance.
Helena returns to her apartment to learn that her mother's operation
  was successful; Helena returns to happily help at the circus. Sometime
  later, Helena becomes fascinated by a young man, strongly resembling
  Valentine, who wants to be a juggler for the circus.





Trailer
